# Unable to run VB script on a remote server using c# Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, psexec

I am trying to Run DelTemp-Final.vbs on a remote server which is being imported from a web portal.
I tried to use native C# to get the task done, No luck. So I opted for PS tools to help me out. I am stuck with he below scenario. Please help

Psexec is working using command prompt, but not working with c#

Below is the command prompt output which is working fine:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DelTemp\Scripts>psexec \\testusit1 -u XXXX\xxxxxxx -p xxxx
Xxxxxxxx -accepteula -i 0 -d c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe /nologo "\\testusi
t2\C$\karthik\DelTemp-Final.vbs"



PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe started on testusit1 with process ID 5452.

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DelTemp\Scripts>psexec \\testusit2 -u XXXX\xxxxxxx -p xxxxx
xxxxxxxxx -accepteula -i 0 -d c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe /nologo "\\testusi
t2\C$\karthik\DelTemp-Final.vbs"

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe started on testusit2 with process ID 7416.
```

Whereas, the same command does not work when included with c# in asp.net

```
Process p=new Process();
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute=false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput=true;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError=true;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput=true;
 p.StartInfo.FileName=@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DelTemp\Scripts\PsExec.exe";

p.StartInfo.Arguments="\\\\"+li.Text+" -u XXXX\\xxxxxx -p xxxxxxxxxxx -accepteula -i 0 -d c:\\windows\\system32\\cscript.exe /nologo \\\\testusit2\\C$\\karthik\\DelTemp-Final.vbs";
p.Start();
 string output=p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 string errormessage=p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
 p.WaitForExit();
 txtValueA.Text +="PSexec argument :" + p.StartInfo.Arguments;
 txtValueA.Text +="<br/> Output : " + output+"| error messsage: "+errormessage;
```

Output of the above code for two servers is as follows:

```
PSexec argument :\\testusit1 -u XXXX\xxxxxxxxxx -p xxxxxxxxxx -accepteula -i 0 -d
c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe /nologo \\testusit2\C$\karthik\DelTemp-Final.vbs Output : | error
messsage: PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich 
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com The handle is invalid. Connecting to testusit1... Starting 
PSEXESVC service on testusit1... Connecting with PsExec service on testusit1... Error deriving 
session key:

PSexec argument :\\testusit2 -u XXXX\xxxxxxxxxxx-p xxxxxxxxxx -accepteula -i 0 -d 
c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe /nologo \\testusit2\C$\karthik\DelTemp-Final.vbs Output : | error 
messsage: PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich 
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com Access is denied. Connecting to testusit2... Starting PSEXESVC 
service on testusit2... Could not start PSEXESVC service on testusit2: Connecting to testusit2... 
Starting PSEXESVC service on testusit2...
```

Please assist.. Is there any changes I need to do to the script? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try directing your output to an event handler instead. I just ran a variation of this on my server with psexec executing ipconfig on the remote machine and I was able to view all output.

```
            Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DelTemp\Scripts\PsExec.exe";

        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "\\\\" + li.Text + " -u XXXX\\xxxxxx -p xxxxxxxxxxx -accepteula -i 0 -d c:\\windows\\system32\\cscript.exe /nologo \\\\testusit2\\C$\\karthik\\DelTemp-Final.vbs";
        p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(p_OutputDataReceived);
        p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(p_ErrorDataReceived);
        p.Start();
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        p.BeginErrorReadLine();
        p.WaitForExit();
        txtValueA.Text += "PSexec argument :" + p.StartInfo.Arguments;
        txtValueA.Text += "<br/> Output : " + output + "| error messsage: " + errormessage;
    }
    public static void p_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }

    //Standard output event handler for PSEXEC
    public static void p_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }
```